# Laravel 6: Problem with credentials for MySQL and e-mail on production server only

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I updated a Laravel app from 5.7 to 5.8 and finally to 6 on my local development server (Homestead). Then I uploaded the app to a production server. I had to update PHP to version 7.2 on the production server. The homepage loads just fine, but when trying to log in there's a database error.

This is from the log file:

```
production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'xxx'@'xxx.xx.xx.xx' (using password: YES)
(SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = xxx@example.org.de limit 1) 
{"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 1045): SQLSTATE[HY000] 
[1045] Access denied for user 'xxx'@'xxx.xx.xx.xx' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from 
`users` where `email` = xxx@example.org limit 1) at 
/html/scouting/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:665)
```

Also, whenever a user logs in, an email should be sent. This isn't working, either:

```
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "xxx" using 2 possible authenticators. 
Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535 5.7.8
Error: authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6".
Authenticator PLAIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535 5.7.8
Error: authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6"
```

I wonder what exactly "Error: authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6" means (*UGFzc3dvcmQ6* is a base64 representation of the string *Password*). Also, in both stack traces there's a mention of `LaravelCaffeineDripMiddleware.php`. I am using Caffeine, which works flawlessly in Homestead (*edit: After disabling Caffeine, this is gone from the stack traces*).

Apart from that, I have no idea what the problem might be. I can still connect to MySQL using Sequel Pro and `.env` has not been modified.

Comment: Have your checked your config/database.php file? This might get changed when upgrading your Laravel application. This is the file that reads from the .env file.

Comment: @thephper I think this file is fine, `mysql` connection is selected with these settings:             `'driver'    => 'mysql', 'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'), 'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'), 'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'), 'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''), 'charset'   => 'utf8', 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 'prefix'    => '', 'strict'    => false`

Comment: Yes that looks okay. Did you by any chance upgrade to mysql 8 in the same process? That might lead to authentication issues.

Comment: No, I'm using MySQL 5.6 (which should be working with Laravel 6).

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question: I had hashes ('#') in both DB and e-mail passwords. These indicate the beginning of a comment in Laravel 5.8 and 6. Wrapping these passwords in quotes solved my issue.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/upgrade#environment-variable-parsing